# is possible to extract bow from gensim lda model

Tags: dataset, gensim

I trained `LDA` model on my preprocessed corpus (i forget to save preprocessed data which was in  form of list of list) Is this possible to recover this data from trained model or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dictionary.id2token to return token from ID.

Following code would work:

dictionary[0]

bow=[(dictionary.id2token(item),count) for item,count in doc for doc in corpus]